# Common ion effect

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, concentration

Let $\ce{HA}$ ($x$ molar) be a strong electrolyte and $\ce{HB}$ ($c$ molar) — weak electrolyte. As $\ce{HA}$ is strong electrolyte, it dissociates completely:

$$
\begin{array}{lcc}
\ce{&HA &-> &H+ &+ &A-} \\
\text{initially} & x && 0 && 0 \\
\text{after} & 0 && x && x
\end{array}
$$

As HB is weak electrolyte

$$
\begin{array}{lcc}
\ce{&HB &-> &H+ &+ &B-} \\
\text{initially} & c && 0 && 0 \\
\text{equilibrium} & c - cα && cα && cα
\end{array}
$$

Then

$$K_\mathrm{a} =\frac{cα\cdot (cα + x)}{c - cα}$$

Now my doubt is how can we add the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ together as their volume can be different. Suppose $x = \pu{1 M}$, and $cα = \pu{0.01 M},$ then how can be the resultant concentration be $\pu{1.01 M}?$ Can someone explain in detail?

Edit:
$\alpha$ is the degree of dissociation
Now let us suppose we had a 'x' molar strong electrolyte and a 'c'  having a common ion let us suppose H. Now while writing Ka for the dissocition of weak electrolyte as given in equation
$$
\begin{array}{lcc}
\ce{&HB &-> &H+ &+ &B-} \\
\text{initially} & c && 0 && 0 \\
\text{equilibrium} & c - cα && cα && cα
\end{array}
$$

Then
$$K_\mathrm{a} =\frac{[B] \cdot [H] }{[HB] }$$
Now due to common ion effect we have to consider the total concentration of H we get which gives us

$$K_\mathrm{a} =\frac{cα\cdot (cα + x)}{c - cα}$$
Now how did the concentration of H become $$(cα + x)$$
Let us now suppose instead of x we had a 2 molar strong electrolyte (HA) so the concentration of H that comes from HA is 2 molar. Now for the weak electrolyte let us suppose we get 0.01M as the concentration of H$(cα) $ that comes from HB now according to the equation
$$K_\mathrm{a} =\frac{cα\cdot (cα + x)}{c - cα}$$
We get the total concentration of H is  (cα + x). Using our supposed value we get total concentration of H as 2+0.01=2.01M but how can we just add the two concentration. Just like in if we had a 1M solution1 and a 2M solution2 we would not get the total concentration of the two solutions after mixing as 3M

Comment: Are x and c the concentrations before mixing or after? What are the different volumes you are talking about?

Comment: Initial concentration

Comment: It is a common ion, so you should have a single variable for the $\ce{H+}$ concentration, and it should appear in the equilibrium expression. The protonation state of the weak electrolyte (just like a pH indicator) will be influenced by the pH of the solution. Another consequence is that the concentration of $\ce{H+}$  will be different from the concentration of  $\ce{B-}$.

Comment: @Satwik It's not the concentration that we add, we add the moles. If the volume is 1 L, then naturally  concentrations get added.